# AWS Lambda function execution time when using AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

I transcode videos with a Lambda function.

Example with Node.js:

```
transcoder.createJob(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

Does the function hang until the video is encoded? Or is the job started then the Lambda function execution stops right away?

Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty easy to see the execution time in the CloudWatch logs.  For example, mine has something like "REPORT RequestId: 1234 Duration: 2.99 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 256 MB Max Memory Used: 45 MB"  That should give you a better idea.

Comment: Yeah I could compare the execution time to some long video transcoding time but ideally I wanted some official doc specifying exactly what happens ;-) It seems like the Lambda function terminates just after calling the transcoder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will wait until the transcoder is done.

https://medium.com/@ratulbasak93/video-to-audio-using-elastic-transcoder-lambda-with-sns-notification-cdc8ba8a6e78

This article will be pretty much helpful and you should use the SNS notification system to let the lambda knows it.

```
Elastic Transcoder, Lambda with SNS Notification
```